# Rails: Unit testing a before_create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd

I am trying to test that a field is being generated properly by a callback, but I can't figure this one out.

**album.rb**

```
before_create :generate_permalink

private
  def generate_permalink
    @title = album.downcase.gsub(/\W/, '_')
    @artist = artist.downcase.gsub(/\W/, '_')
    self.permalink =  @artist + "-" + @title
  end
```

**album_test.rb**

```
test "should return a proper permalink" do
  album = Album.new(:artist=>'Dead Weathers', :album=>'Primary Colours')
  album.save
  assert_equal "dead_weathers-primary_colours", album.permalink 
end
```

But this doesn't work because `album.permalink` won't return the value if it's saved.

Is there a way to test a `before_create`? Should I be doing this at the controller level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found [this blog post](http://www.oreillynet.com/ruby/blog/2006/10/test_tidbits.html) that might be of interest to you.

In short it mentions that you can call the callback yourself by using the send method with the callback as its parameter. In this case you can force album to call the before_create callback by using

```
album.send(:before_create)
```

Comment: thanks, that worked with:
    album.send(:generate_permalink)
with the method name instead of :before_create

Comment: Oops, forgot to read the whole blog post, and was not at my home machine to test. Yeah, it is name of the method you want to call, not the call back. Apparently this is a hack for calling private methods.