# Testing Rails ActiveRecord before_create method with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, activerecord, rspec

I found [that stackoverflow old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993941/rails-unit-testing-a-before-create) that suggests `model_entity.send(:before_create)` but now it doesn't work. So, how can I test method that should execute `before create, update, destroy`.There is another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605199/testing-before-create-method-in-rspec-and-rails-3) but i can't figure out, what I should do in my case.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_create do |user|
    user.secure_token = UUID.new.generate
  end
end
```

The point is I can just make a method with this code, and call it. Is there any other ways?

In general, if I want to test after_create method, that only have in my model at all, I should create Model Object and check it. But, I guess, it's unnecessary actions. I could just check this method without creation any instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using rspec, I'm guessing you can do:

```
@user = User.new
@user.should_receive(:secure_token)
@user.save
```

Comment: So, if it shouldn't receive it throws something? How can I form it as test.     `before(:each) do
      @user = User.new
   end
    it "should have a secure_token" do
      @user.should_receive(:secure_token)
      @user.save
   end`

Comment: As an errors says, your test expects "during save your object is calling 'secure_token' method once", but somehow your code is calling this method two times. It looks like, there is some other callback method (in User object) which is setting secure_token on this object.

Comment: Yes, there is a validation. If it calls, so it does call twice.

Comment: So you can do two things: @user.should_receive(:secure_token).twice, or @user.save(:validate => false) (saving without validation)

Comment: shouldn't it be `@user.should_receive(:secure_token=)` note the `=`...?

Answer (score 5):

There's a dry way of doing this:

```
expect{ user.save }.to change{ user.secure_token }
```

Answer (score 3):

Just found something tricky. If you need to validate the actual result, validate that separately, because the current rspec doesn't pass the return value of the function `:secure_token=` if you use the `.should_receive(:secure_token=)`. Example:

Model as above:

```
describe "verifies that secure_token= is called" do
  @user = User.new
  @user.should_receive(:secure_token=)
  @user.save
end

describe "verifies the result is set" do
  @user = User.new
  @user.save
  expect(@user.secure_token).not_to be_empty
end
```

But if you put the expect not to be empty in the same test as the should_receive, then the test will fail.